# ¿How i can disable CSRF only for my api with spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-tool-suite

Im creating a project with spring using spring security but i am having problem only with my api(all controllers are working correctly with csrf). But seems like the csrf is causing problem to my api, because when i make a request to my api i get:

```
{"id":41,"titulo":"vineta3","creationdate":1489421003000,"URL":"http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/125/918/RMUBQ.png","likes":0,"dislikes":0,"descripcion":"des3"}{"timestamp":1489421218765,"status":200,"error":"OK","exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","message":"Cannot create a session after the response has been committed","path":"/api/vineta/41/"}
```

The last info:

```
{"timestamp":1489421218765,"status":200,"error":"OK","exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","message":"Cannot create a session after the response has been committed","path":"/api/vineta/41/"}
```

is not returning when my project has not spring secutiry. Im using the next code for my security configuration.

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public UserRepositoryAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // Public pages
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/loginerror").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/registro").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll();        


    // Private pages (all other pages)
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home").hasAnyRole("USER");
    //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/crearComentario/vineta/{id}").hasAnyRole("USER");

    // Login form
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login");
    http.formLogin().usernameParameter("username");
    http.formLogin().passwordParameter("password");
    http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/home");
    http.formLogin().failureUrl("/loginerror");

    // Logout
    http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    // Database authentication provider
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}
```

}

and the next for my csrf:

```
@Configuration
public class CSRFHandlerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CSRFHandlerInterceptor());
    }
}

class CSRFHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler,
            final ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf"); 
        modelAndView.addObject("token", token.getToken());      
    }
}
```

In the console, i can see the follow logs:
at

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
```

Im not using SingleTransactionsController, this can be the problem?

Comment: after a changes now i obtain: {"timestamp":1489421060885,"status":200,"error":"OK","exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","message":"Cannot create a session after the response has been committed","path":"/api/usuarios/"}

and, on my console i see:
ERROR 32628 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Answer (score 12):

I don't understand why you use `CSRFHandlerInterceptor`, but if you want to disable CRSF only for API, I have two solutions:

1. You can inject a `requireCsrfProtectionMatcher` to CSRF filter, for example:

   ```
    http
        .csrf()
            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(newAndRequestMatcher(CsrfFilter.DEFAULT_CSRF_MATCHER, new RegexRequestMatcher("^(?!/api/)", null)));
   ```

   The default matcher is method matcher, and the second matcher is used for **not** `/api/` request.
2. You can create a new Spring Security config only for `/api`, and set the order before default Spring Security config, match the API URL without CSRF:

   ```
   http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")).csrf().disable();
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Another way to enable security for both API and Web is to include this in your SecurityConfig class:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(....)
            //form login etc
            .and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**");
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Csrf settings are global in Spring Security

This can help:

```
http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new RequestMatcher() {

        private Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");
       // regex to match your api url 
        private RegexRequestMatcher apiMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("/v[0-9]*/.*", null);

        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            // No CSRF due to allowedMethod
            if(allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches())
                return false;

            // No CSRF due to api call
            if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/view/cpanel/Login.jsp");
                return false;

            // CSRF for everything else that is not an API call or an allowedMethod
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If your API uses something other than a session cookie for authentication, like basic auth or an API token, then a simple way to allow just those requests through is:

```java
.csrf()
    .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AndRequestMatcher(
        CsrfFilter.DEFAULT_CSRF_MATCHER,
        new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher(HttpHeaders.COOKIE)));
```